# Firebase off removes all callbacks for all eventTypes

Tags: javascript, firebase

When I call `off` on a reference for a specific eventType, firebase seems to be removing all callbacks for all event types.  In the code below, I want to remove all callbacks for the `child_removed` event while preserving callbacks for the `child_added` event.  Am I doing this wrong?

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.3.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
var root_ref = new Firebase('https://jcatest.firebaseio.com');
root_ref.on('child_added', function(snap){
  console.log('child:', snap.key(), snap.val());
});
root_ref.off('child_removed');
root_ref.child('foo_key').set('foo_val');
</script>
```

From the firebase docs:

> "If a callback is not specified, all callbacks for the specified eventType will be removed."
>   https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/off.html

I realize I could pass the callback as the second parameter, but I'd like to avoid doing that if possible.  The docs seem to indicate this is possible.

Comment: I ran a few tests and it's slightly more involved: when you call `off('child_removed')` Firebase stops firing `child_*` events. If you have a `value` event listener, *that* will continue to fire after `off('child_removed')`. I'll ask around if that is the expected behavior.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Any updates?

Comment: It indeed looks like a bug in the Firebase SDK. No timeline for a fix though, so you might want to work around it for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.3.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
    var root_ref = new Firebase('https://jcatest.firebaseio.com');

    var refChidAdded = root_ref.on('child_added', function(snap){
      console.log('child:', snap.key(), snap.val());
    });

    //change here
    var refChidRemoved = root_ref.on('child_removed', function(snap){
      console.log('child:', snap.key(), snap.val());
    });
    refChidRemoved.off(); // OR root_ref.off('child_removed', refChidRemoved );

    root_ref.child('foo_key').set('foo_val');
    </script>
```

Please call off() from the reference created by on() event.

Also, possible by removing maintenance of extra variables, do this directly :

```
 root_ref.on('child_removed').off()
```

Comment: Yeah, I realize I can do this.  I'd like to avoid having to track a bunch of extra variables though.

Comment: By avoid extra variables : root_ref.on('child_removed').off()

Comment: The correct syntax is `root_ref.off('child_removed', refChidRemoved);` (the on() method returns the function, not a ref).