# In firebase how to unmount a specific connection to an event

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my realtime database I have these data trees are currently running (A, B, C, D). I want to implement a reference disconnection method (like `firebase.database().ref().off()`) that can disconnect a specific real-time database reference. For example, if I click a button A, the reference for data A will be turned off while other references still exists. Is there any way like that to do that in firebase?

Comment: Some of the terms you're using (instance, unmount, terminate) don't have a clearly defined meaning in the context of the Firebase database. This makes it hard to understand what you're trying to do. Can you edit your question to show the [minimal complete code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces where you are stuck?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, Thank you for your remind, I just changed my words.

Comment: Do you mean you added *observers* to nodes A, B, C, D and want to remove one of the observers so you are no longer notified of events within that node? Can you update your question with some code so we fully understand what your use case is?

Comment: @Jay, Precisely, that's exactly what I need. In fact, I don't know how to code that, that's why I asked this question

Comment: There are a details provided on the [Firebase Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) (Swift) - check the Detach Listeners section as well as a whole bunch of questions/answers here on SO. You didn't list your platform or if you've tried anything so far. Can you update and clarify your question? Oh, and check the [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseReference#-removeobserverwithhandle) for removeObserverWithHandle (Swift). There are equivalent options for other platforms as well.

Comment: @Jay, is there any similar documents in javascript you can share with me?

Comment: Did you look through the documentation on the Firebase website? It's in the Javascript section [Javascript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) and the function is 'off(eventType, callback, context)'. There are a couple dozen question/answers here on SO as well. There's a *Search...* function at the top of this webpage. Usage would be like this *[Firebase][Javascript]remove listener. That results in some good info [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964226/firebase-off-removes-all-callbacks-for-all-eventtypes)

Comment: @Jay Yes I found it, thank you :)